# Failed Wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, ipv4

Sorry i'm not good with computers so my tech. talk is limited. I have a presario CQ62 Notebook PC. 64 bit:

Yesterday I went to the local Library to use some free internet. When I returned I could no longer get my wireless connection. I have full strengh of connection. I just have a yellow ^ with ! inside it. 
When i open the Network and Sharing I have a Big red X between my Network -----X------ Internet.
Status reads: IPv4 Connectivity:    No Internet access   (IPv6 is ok)
Network Connections: Wireless Network 2:  'Not Connected'

I live in a Hostel with 90 other people. They all get it. I am getting it on this Laptop I am writing on. So it isn't anything but the laptop trouble. I have upgraded the Drivers: Device Manager>Network Adapters> ....  I have spend all my time searching for the answer. I have done the ipconfig scan. Hope it helps: Please advise. Sorry I am not computerminded. So tech terms I will likely not understand.

cheers, Brian

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\new owner>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : mpk-lappy-3
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-F1-A1-57-65-A7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8191SE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapte
r
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-F1-A1-57-65-A7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1c59:ede9:95a9:a3e5%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.146.139(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.192.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 1 April 2014 12:19:34 p.m.
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 1 April 2014 6:19:36 p.m.
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.128.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.128.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 326168993
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-3B-81-53-C8-0A-A9-7B-97-4D

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 114.134.15.250
                                       114.134.15.251
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-0A-A9-7B-97-4D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{71B11DCD-5BB4-4DD4-8871-1FC0533E7683}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1ccb:3817:f5e1:6d74(Pref
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1ccb:3817:f5e1:6d74%24(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

C:\Users\new owner>